# Should nested class marked as static if only contains final static fields?

Tags: java

I am using a class to store some strings which I can access across the application. It looks like:

```
public final class Settings {
    public final static class Setting1 {
        public final static String CONFIG = "A config string";
        private Setting1 (){};
    }
    public final class Setting2 {
        public final static String CONFIG = "A config string";
        private Setting2 (){};
    }
}
```

I have found I can use either static nested class (e.g. Setting1) or inner class (e.g. Setting2). They both can be used in the same way:

```
System.out.println(Settings.Setting1.CONFIG); // Print: A config string
System.out.println(Settings.Setting2.CONFIG); // Print: A config string
```

So if the nested class will only contain final static fields, are there any different in using these two? Because of the private constructor, no instantiation is allowed. Does that mean these two classes are the same now?

Comment: Just in this case, it would be more useful to use just unmodifiable `List` of `Strings`. But, answer for your question is - yes, that should be `static` inner class, because you need only one instance of this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested/inner class should be marked static if it does not access the this of the outer class, no non-static fields or methods of the  outer class.

In fact it is the other way around: a non-static inner class has an overhead of an outer this: a `Settings.this` besides the normal `this`.

So yes, in your case certainly. The reason / role of that inner class is of course style / namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to store only static final fields, then **enum** will be better choice than inner class. In fact, you are `storing constants using static final fields` and **enum** are provided for this purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in storing such constants. But it's usually not a good code-style.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Ordinary constants should always be `static` and `final` (and immutable, which is not the same thing as `final`).  *If* you are going to do it the way you have the inner classes should be static too.  You should probably include a private constructor too - to prevent instances of these classes (the inner or the outer) being created.

That said, what would be wrong with?

```
public final class Settings {
    private Settings() { ; }
    public static final String SETTING_1 = "A config string";
    public static final String SETTING_2 = "Another config string";
}
```

Re the answer from Florescent Ticket:

Enums are *not* for storing static final fields (though their members *are* static final fields).  They are for defining a typed, bounded set (with or without further attributes on the members of the set).  A typical example is `public enum Suit { HEART, CLUB, SPADE, DIAMOND };`.

You *could* represent your Settings this way (with a single String attribute on each member of the enum) but there is no real reason why you should.  It *might* be helpful if you routinely need to deal with sets of settings (and I mean sets of settings - not sets of the *values* of those settings).  On the other hand, it might be less than helpful if you want settings that are not just strings.

The simplest starting point is probably too just define a class with `public static final`  constants (they should be immutable too, of course) of the appropriate values - whether strings or whatever.  But if you want inner classes (perhaps to group the settings) then the inner classes should be `static` and `final` (and ideally, also have a private constructor, to prevent instances).

Comment: Hi Paul,thanks for the suggestion. I use nested class to group things. I have updated the code a bit. So now, what is the purpose to use "static"? For a better coding style?